# Python/Django Setting up a database model with conditions inside of it

Tags: python, django, database, model

I am currently writing some sort of simple game, which is set up onto a database backend (using Python with Django).
I have a database model called Character, which basically has two fields (there are more, but they are not relevant for my question).

It basically looks something like this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here

class Character(models.Model):

HUMAN= 'HM'
ELF = 'EF'

RACE_CHOICES = [
    (HUMAN, 'Human'),
    (ELF, 'Elf'),
]
    race = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=RACE_CHOICES)
    constitution = models.FloatField
```

Basically you can choose a race from the two given above.
I want humans to have more constitution than elfs, so the constitution should be dependent on what race the user picks.
I know that this is possible by overwriting the save method, but I am also aware that this is not best practice as it can crash the whole database, should any errors occur.

I was told that is is, however, possible to use conditions inside the model definition, what I basically need is:

```
if race == human:
    constitution = 12.0f

else:
    constitution = 8.0f
```

I really don't know how to set this up inside a Django model.

Or would it be a better way to define a meta class "Race" and make "Human" and "Elf" inherit from it and set the constitution there? However, I am not quite sure on how to set this up inside my character model since it still needs to be decided wether a character has the elfs or human constitution.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `constitution` field if it is a *functional dependency* of `race`, you can implement a property:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    HUMAN = 'HM'
    ELF = 'EF'

    RACE_CHOICES = [
        (HUMAN, 'Human'),
        (ELF, 'Elf'),
    ]
    race = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=RACE_CHOICES)

    @property
    def constitution(self):
        if self.race == Character.HUMAN:
            return 12.0
        else:
            return 8.0
```

> Or would it be a better way to define a meta class "Race" and make "Human" and "Elf" inherit from it and set the constitution there?

You can make a model `Race` that has a `constitution` value, depending on that `Race`. We thus make then two or more records: human, elf, and different ones:

```
class Race(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    constitution = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Character(models.Model):
    race = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def constitution(self):
        return self.race.constitution
```

Comment: Hey and thanks for your input. I tried the first way you mentioned, however, I don't seem to have any database field storing the constitution then. As for the second way: I tried that and created the two races inside the database and created characters inside the database as well. The only thing I still don't get is: how can I access (i.e. print, show etc.) the constitution value I defined for the specific race if I am working with the character object?
I have a character called Elrond and he is Elf (which has 8.0 constitution), how can I display Elronds constitution?
Thank you! :)

Comment: @MaddinS.: no, it is not necessary to store it in the database, since it is completely dependent on `race`. But if you thus use `my_character.constitution`, Python will determine the value based on the `race`, so not at the database level, but the Django/Python level.

Comment: Okay, so if I get you right, something like this should be possible:

`elrond = Character.constitution`

but I get:
`Exception Value:type object 'Character' has no attribute 'constitution'`
trying so :(

Comment: @MaddinS.: no, just `elrond.constitution`, if `elrond` is a `Character` object.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.
But if I let's say want to print out Elronds constitution on a simple web page:
`def characterList(request): return HttpResponse({{elrond.constitution}})`

it says:
`name 'elrond' is not defined`

Comment: @MaddinS.: you first need to fetch it from the database, something like `elrond = Character.objects.get(name='elrond')`.